# troubleshooting with facebook permissions to upload a video

Tags: php, facebook, video, upload

I need to create a facebook app that will upload a video directly to the wall of the logged in user. I followed the steps in the facebook documentation. I get an access token with the correct permissions to write on a wall. Despite this, I still have the same error message.

**Graph returned an error: (# 100) No permission to publish the video**

I have already gone through the official document but I can not find anything.

If ever, I'm on a test app with test users.

I can add a post, upload an image but NOT videos.

If anyone has an idea or has already been confronted with this problem, be nice, enlighten me.

thank you in advance

Comment: _“I get an access token with the correct permissions to write on a wall”_ - and which one(s) would that be, exactly? `publish_actions` permission is deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#live-api-4-24: _“In the coming weeks, a new permission model that allows apps to publish Videos to their User's Groups and Timelines will be announced.”_

Comment: I use now this permission : publish_to_groups that must replace publish_actions